# throw new sfValidatorError in action Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I generated with Doctrine simply action:

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $test = $form->save();

      $this->redirect('test/show?id='.$test->getId());
    }
  }
```

Is possible add for this **sfValidatorError** ?
For example:

```
    protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
      {
        $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));

if(strtotime('now') % 2){
               throw new sfValidatorError('aaa', 'bbb', array();
            } 

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
          $test = $form->save();

          $this->redirect('test/show?id='.$test->getId());
        }
      }
```

This of course doesnt working, because sfValidatorError must extends sfValidatorBase. Is possible make this in Symfony 1.4?

Comment: Please elaborare on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing that you just want to add new validator, not throw an sfValidatorError (especially that sfValidatorError must have a reference to sfValidator which throwed it)

unfortunately I don't have environment to test these code snippets, but they will give you general concepts.

first: create your validator class

```
class timestampIsNotEvenValidator extends sfValidatorBase {
    protected function doClean($value) {
        if(strtotime('now') % 2){
           throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'timestamp is not even');
        }
        return $value; //this return is critical!
    }
}
```

then: add the validator to your form (but better do it in forms configure method):

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
    $form->mergePostValidator(new timestampIsNotEvenValidator());
    $form->bind(...);

    if ($form->isValid()) { //false if timestampIsNotEventValidator throwed sfValidatorError
    }
```

you can then render global errors (throwed by post validator) in your template by calling

```
//indexSuccess.php
$form->renderGlobalErrors();
```

or if you want to bind error to specific field of your form (i.e. if you have "field" type in your form and you want error thrown by global validator to display as "field" error, not global one) you can alter your validator:

```
//i dont know if following solution is the best one there is, but it works
class timestampIsNotEvenValidator extends sfValidatorBase {
    protected function doClean($value) {
        if(strtotime('now') % 2){
           throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this, array(
               'field' => new sfValidatorError($this, 'timestamp is not even')
           ));
        }
        return $value; //this return is critical!
    }
}
```

and for reference - post validator will get an array of all fields values of the form as $value argument in clean method.